# Having user logged in can access each website page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have an idea for a website that would have user accounts, they would have to log into a home/dashboard page (log in details would be extracted from a database), and then they would have access to other pages, but, I do not want them to have to log in every time they go onto a new page, how do I go about allowing the website to know that they are already logged in and to store their log in data to allow them to go between pages while remaining logged in, or am I overthinking this and their is a much simpler solution?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sessions/cookies and a userbase.

Comment: Should be "I have an idea..." and other errors. Besides you're overthinking session cookies on user side define if user is logged or not. If user deletes session cookie or if cookie expires session is over.

Comment: As HTTP is a stateless protocol, you need some way of identifying a returning visitor.  A cookie can be used as an identifier.  See Php sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_SESSION variables

When only a logged in user can enter a page, add this to the top of the page:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

And after the login check add:

```
sesssion_start();    
$_SESSION['user'] = $userid; // replace $userid with the id of the user or whatever user key you'd like to retrieve your user info with later
```